# jscrollpane gallery cutting off last image

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I am a web designer helping a new client change out some photos in a horizontal scroll gallery on an existing web site.  She mentioned she's always had a problem with the last photos in her gallery not always showing up.  If you refresh the page, it shows up but not when the page initially loads.  Sometimes the last photo is missing completely, other times it'll show a small strip of it but the rest is cut off unless we refresh.

I have no experience with horizontal jscrollpane galleries. I keep trying to use Control+K and paste the code in the body of this post for you to see but I get an error.   If it's something you need to see in action, please be kind enough to respond and I will send you the url.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

do need but im willing to bet that somewhere you have a number that is 1 less then it should be. if you have something like var[n] n has an offset of 0. what that means if you put 5 pictures into an array. the last picture is accessed as picture[4] and not picture[5] because arrays start counting at 0. however if somewhere its getting array length that will be 5 because length starts counting at 1.

please post link so we can see the code.